# Python cx_Oracle unable to insert XMLType in Oracle 11g database using a stored procedure

Tags: python, xml, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I am trying to call a stored procedure in Python to insert XML data but it is not working :(

here are details -

```
create or replace procedure t(a in XMLType, b out number) as
begin
  b := 5;
end;
/
```

code is -

```
xmlData = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <customer>
            <name>John Smith</name>
            <Age>43</Age>
            <Designation>Professor</Designation>
            <Subject>Mathematics</Subject>
        </customer>"""
xmlval=cx_Oracle.CLOB
xmlval = xmlData
try:
  
    r=c.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
    c.callproc("T", [xmlval,r])
    print("Result = ",r.getvalue(pos=0))
 
    c.close()
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as ex:
    err, =ex.args
    print("Error code    = ",err.code)
    print("Error Message = ",err.message)
    os._exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't actually a answer, but i can't comment because i don't have 50 reputation.

but you could try setting the valor of xmlval like this:

```
xmlval=cx_Oracle.CLOB
xmlval.setvalue(0, xmlData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as a CLOB to a wrapper function or anonymous PL/SQL block like:

```py
c.execute("begin t(sys.xmltype(:xmlval),:r); end;", [xmlval,r])
```

There is some background about binding LOBs regarding XMLType in the [cx_Oracle manual](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/xml_data_type.html).